# Add button inside the label but without changing any styles

Tags: html, css, button, header, accessibility

I have the code on my website with a header: `<h3 class="label" type="button">`
It is an accordion so I'd like to make it more accessible by changing it to:
`<h3 class="label"><button aria-expanded="true">`. But it adds some styling on top for the button. I don't want this, I would like to keep the styling that is now. Is there any efficient way to do this, other than just styling the special class of the button?

Comment: Not sure if you had a typo but `type` is not a valid attribute on an <h3>. Perhaps you had `role="button"`? If so, that breaks the 2nd rule of ARIA, https://www.w3.org/TR/aria-in-html/#second

Answer (score 1):

It needs `all: inherit` style, can be added inline.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a [global](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/all) inherit to the button element:

```
button.aria-button {
    all: inherit;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
}
```

and html:

```
<h3 class="label">
    <button class="aria-button" aria-expanded="true">
        {yourText}
    </button>
</h3>
```